# rqt_plot in ROS 2?

Tags: ros2, rqt, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to check the data in topic with realtime plotting, and I know there was rqt_plot in ROS 1.
However, I could not found rqt_plot in ROS 2 humble.
Moreover, I could not use correctly rqt -> Plugins -> Visualization -> Plot.
How to use rqt_plot or similar app in ROS 2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411898/rqt_plot-in-ros-2?/) by [Mohumohu Usagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/135477/mohumohu-usagi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to use [PlotJuggler](https://www.plotjuggler.io/) instead.

I'd almost go as far as to write "forget about `rqt_plot`".

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohumohu Usagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/135477/mohumohu-usagi/) on 2023-01-31**:
Thanks. I will search for PlotJuggler.