# Confirm ROS2 (Humble) IMU node working correctly?

Tags: ros2, imu, ros-humble

I recently added an MPU9250 9dof IMU to my robot and configured [ros2_mpu9250_driver](https://github.com/hiwad-aziz/ros2_mpu9250_driver)

How can I confirm the IMU and ROS2 node are working correctly, and the orientation output is configured correctly.

I see /imu topics:

```
$ ros2 topic echo --once --flow-style /imu
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1701139672
    nanosec: 166159626
  frame_id: base_link
orientation:
  x: -0.00013199338433265485
  y: -0.003050688240073104
  z: -0.7370080372140175
  w: 0.6758770812514282
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity:
  x: 0.6774427480915985
  y: 3.1466335877862592
  z: -1.001618320610687
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration:
  x: 0.28355115234375006
  y: 0.042684038085936626
  z: 9.88417614990236
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

but how can I visualize the orientation the IMU thinks versus the orientation from the wheel encoders /odom topic?

ps. the IMU QoS is set to sensor_data (best effort)

Comment: You mean something other than looking at the IMU topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `imu_tools` has a RViz plugin that can be used to visualize the IMU topic:

https://github.com/CCNYRoboticsLab/imu_tools

Answer (score 1):

As given in this answer [rqt_plot in ROS 2?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/102973/rqt-plot-in-ros-2), you can use `rqt_plot` in ROS1 or PlotJuggler https://plotjuggler.io in ROS2 to plot your vector components. You can also show the TFs in RViz.